# How to stop CSS Code Display:none for specific id or class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML

```
<p>Author: <a href='(Link)' id='Mycr'>Ramy</a></p>
```

It's for copyrights for my work.

How can I stop users from using code similar to

```
#mycr{ 
    display:none 
}
```

to remove my rights?

How to stop this code if the user use it in the future using CSS, JavaScript, Jquery, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine inline styles with !important:

```
<p style="display:block!important;visibility:visible!important;position:relative!important;color:black!important;">
   Author: <a href='(Link)' id='Mycr'>Ramy</a>
</p>
```

It is pretty messed up but it will probably have effect in most of the cases.

Second Rikudo user type proof (the force is strong with this one):

```
setTimeout(function(){ document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('DIV').innerHTML = "<p style='display:block!important;visibility:visible!important;position:relative!important;color:black!important;'>
   Author: <a href='(Link)' id='Mycr'>Ramy</a>
</p>";); }, 1000);
```

DOM observer counter:

```
setInterval(function(){
  if(document.getElementById('Mycr'))
    return;
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('DIV').innerHTML = "<p style='display:block!important;visibility:visible!important;position:relative!important;color:black!important;'>
   Author: <a href='(Link)' id='Mycr'>Ramy</a>
</p>";); }, 1000);
```

Comment: `var copyrightP = document.getElementById('Mycr').parentNode; copyrightP.parentNode.removeChild(copyrightP);`

Comment: That would add hundreds of such elements to the DOM, and I can always set a DOM Observer to remove them instantly.

Answer (score 5):

You can't. You can't control what a determined user would do. Whatever protections you might use, the attacker can place an even more specific selector and use `!important`.

And at the worst case, he can remove the node entirely from the DOM.

The client is not an environment you control, deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Over write the code with display block. or you can use !important